# How to split a string with conditions

Tags: java, regex, string, split

When splitting a string, how can I make sure that **if the delimiter is located between two characters then it won't be considered**?

```
// Input
String string = "a,b,[c,d],e";
String[] split = string.split(",");
// Output
split[0] // "a"
split[1] // "b"
split[2] // "[c"
split[3] // "d]"
split[4] // "e"
// Required
split[0] // "a"
split[1] // "b"
split[2] // "[c,d]"
split[3] // "e"
```

Comment: What did you attempt that didnt work?

Comment: Yep need an actual example of what you want to accomplish, and what failed.
A shot in the dark though: \b is a word boundary, it might help you. Also \s is for any space (space, tab...) character, might help you too.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without an example, but it may be that you will need to write a simple finite state machine parser if your requirements are sufficiently idiosyncratic.

Comment: Can brackets ever be nested? `a,b,[c,d,[e,f],g],h`?

Comment: What do you expect for repeated commas? `a,,b,[c,d],,e`? (Perhaps moot at this point.)

Comment: @DavidConrad There should not be. If you can, throw a custom exception, else, leave an empty string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*<sup>Preferred approach at the end of the answer</sup>*

It seems you are looking for [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism.

For instance if you want to split on whitespace which has no `foo` before and no `bar` after it your code can look like

```
split("(?<!foo)\\s(?!bar)")
```

---

**Update** (assuming that there can't be any nested `[...]` and they are well formatted for instance all `[` are closed with `]`):

Your case seems little more complex. What you can do is accept `,` if

- it doesn't have any `[` or `]` after it,
- or if first opening bracket `[` after this comma, has no closing bracket `]` between this comma and itself, otherwise it would mean that comma is inside of area like

  ```
  [ , ] [
    ^ ^ ^ - first `[` after tested comma
    | +---- one `]` between tested comma and first `[` after it
    +------ tested comma
  ```

So your code can look like
<sub>(this is original version, but below is little simplified one)</sub>

```
split(",(?=[^\\]]*(\\[|$))")
```

This regex is based on idea that commas you don't want to accept are inside `[foo,bar]`. But how to determine that we are inside (or outside) such block?

1. if character is inside then there will be no `[` character after it, until we find `]` (next `[` can appear after found `]` like in case `[a,b],[c,d]` comma between `a` and `b` has no `[` until it finds `]`, but there can be some new area `[..]` after it which ofcourse starts with `[`)
2. if character are outside `[...]` area then next after it can appear only non `]` characters, until we find start of `[...]` area, or we will read end of string.

Second case is the one you are interested in. So we need to create regex which will accept `,` which has only non `]` after it (it is not inside `[...]`) until it finds `[` or read end of string (represented by `$`)

Such regex can be written as

- `,` comma
- `(?=...)` which has after it
- `[^\\]]*(\\[|$)`

  - `[^\\]]*` zero or more non `]` characters (`]` need to be escaped as metacharacter)
  - `(\\[|$)` which have `[` (it also needs to be escaped in regex) or end of string after it

**Little simplified split version**

```
string.split(",(?![^\\[]*\\])");
```

Which means: split on comma `,` which after it has no (represented by `(?!...)`) unclosed `]` (unclosed `]` has no `[` between tested comma and itself which can be written as `[^\\[]*\\]`)

---

**Preferred approach**

To avoid such complex regex don't use `split` but Pattern and Matcher classes, which will search for areas like `[...]` or non-comma words.

```
String string = "a,b,[c,d],e";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]|[^,]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
a
b
[c,d]
e
```

Comment: @Joiner Which parts should I explain? [Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[..]`? Negated character class `[^..]`? `OR` operator `|`? End of string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`?

Comment: For example, I can't understand `(?<!foo)\\s(?!bar)`: `(?!bar)` does not have the `>` character, why? And I know `\s`, not `\\s`. See Mati Cicero's edit.

Comment: @Joiner One is negative-look-behind `(?<!...)` and the other without `<` is negative-look-ahead `(?!...)` it is all explained in link about look-around mechanism I gave at start of my answer.

Comment: @Joiner "*And I know `\s`, not `\\s`*" to create ``\`` literal in Java String which you could pass to regex engine you need to escape it, so String representing ``\`` needs to be written as `"\\"`. That is why to create `\s` you need to write it as `"\\s"` (if that is what you asked).

Answer (score 2):

A simple Regex will satisfy your needs:

```
(?<!\[\w),(?!\w\])
```

This regular expression means the following:

- `(?<!\[\w)` = The match cannot be *after* a `[x` where **x** is ***any character***
- `,` = The match should be a **comma**
- `(?!\w\])` = The match cannot be *before* a `x]` where **x** is ***any character***

You may use it as follows:

```
String[] split = text.split("(?<!\\[\\w),(?!\\w\\])");
```

**Output**:

```
a
b
[c,d]
e
```

Comment: `(?!\w\])`: I see `\w\]`. Where is `x]`? And why `(?<!\[\w)` is not `(?<![\w\)`?

Comment: The `x` was just an example showing that it could be _any_ character. In Regular Expressions, _any character_ is expressed as **\w**. Also, in Regular Expressions, the **[** is a reserved keyword or character, and is used for ranges, so, in order to tell the compiler we want the **explicit [**, we should escape it by using the back slash, therefore we shall write it as `\[`

Comment: `"a":["b","c"]` split with `(?<!\\[\\w),(?!\\w\\])` returns `"a":["b"` **and** `"c"]`.

Comment: I formulated my Regular Expression to be compatible with your provided code `a,b,[c,d],e`