# Java Regex match a special character excpet when it is within parentheses

Tags: java, regex, match

given the following string:

```
foo().bar(norf.qux).fubar()
```

I want to split it by the dots except when they're within parentheses, where the output would be:

```
foo()
bar(norf.qux)
fubar()
```

is this possible?

Comment: "*is this possible?*" [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25293211/1393766), but if you can infinitely nest such expression then don't use regex here. Write your own parser.

Comment: One basic question: can you nest parenthesis? In other words, is something like `foo().bar(norf.qux()).fubar()` or `foo().bar(norf.qux(buz.whatever())).fubar()` possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input string by dot which was not enclosed within brackets.

```
\.(?![^()]*\))
```

In Java String representing this regex would be,

```
"\\.(?![^()]*\\))"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/46)

```
String[] tok = s.split("\\.(?![^()]*\\))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

**Output:**

```
[foo(), bar(norf.qux), fubar()]
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

```
\.                       '.'
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                           more times)
  \)                       ')'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: thanks it's the second expression I was looking for!

Comment: You don't need to look for `)` in `[^()]*`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regex like this:

```
\B\.
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kE6yQ8/1)**

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but I am afraid that OP is looking for regex which will split based on if `.` was not inside parenthesis, not if it was not after `)`. In that case we could simply split on `(?<=[)])\.`.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, I agree with you but just posted the answer because of OP sample text. This simple regex works for his example, it might be useful for him

Comment: That is OK, I am not OP so I can't definitely tell if your answer is wrong or not. I just posted my comment to add information about assumptions of your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, helpful too. This suites my scenario at the moment but I'm afraid that in the future I catch this one `foo().bar(norf.qux).fubar().bar(norf.qux)` and the output will be `foo().bar(norf.qux)
fubar()
bar(norf.qux)` not the expected, but thanks ;)

Comment: Hi @Lucas, thanks for the comment. Just for you to know, it also works for the example you mentioned http://regex101.com/r/kE6yQ8/2

Comment: Yeah you're right! this was what I tried to say `foo.bar(norf.qux).fubar.bar(norf.qux)`. sorry